# Filter factory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, filter

I have difficulties with understanding what is happening in this example for creating a filter factory. As far as I understand, a factory is supposed to generate a filter.

```
public static EndpointFilterDelegate ValidateIdFactory(
    EndpointFilterFactoryContext context,
    EndpointFilterDelegate next)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = context.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

    int? idPosition = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
        if (parameters[i].Name == "id" && parameters[i].ParameterType == typeof(string))
        {
            idPosition = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!idPosition.HasValue)
    {
        return next;
    }

    return async (invocationContext) =>
    {
        string id = invocationContext.GetArgument<string>(idPosition.Value);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || !id.StartsWith('s'))
        {
            return Results.ValidationProblem(new Dictionary<string, string[]>
            {
                { "id", new[] { "Id cannot be null or empty and must start with 's'" } }
            });
        }

        return await next(invocationContext);
    };
}
```

I understand that we are looping through the parameters to check for the details we need - a string id parameter, in this case. What exactly are the EndpointFilterFactoryContext and EndpointFilterDelegate? What part of the framework does pass them to the factory function and how does it happen?

What I am confused about the most is this exact part of the code:

```
return async (invocationContext) =>
{
    string id = invocationContext.GetArgument<string>(idPosition.Value);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || !id.StartsWith('s'))
    {
        return Results.ValidationProblem(new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            { "id", new[] { "Id cannot be null or empty and must start with 's'" } }
        });
    }

    return await next(invocationContext);
};
```

Where does the invocationContext come from? There are so many returns and awaits that it's difficult for me to follow. Can someone tell me what's happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly are the EndpointFilterFactoryContext and EndpointFilterDelegate? What part of the framework does pass them to the factory function and how does it happen?

The `EndpointFilterFactoryContext` is a context object that exposes information about the route handler being intercepted.

The [`EndpointFilterDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointfilterdelegate?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) type that represents invocation of the filter chain (it's like ASP.NET Core middleware but instead the shape is different because of filters).

The filter is being returned at the end of the function:

```
// This is it fully spelled out as a function
async ValueTask<object> Filter(EndpointFilterInvocationContext invocationContext)
{
    string id = invocationContext.GetArgument<string>(idPosition.Value);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || !id.StartsWith('s'))
    {
        return Results.ValidationProblem(new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            { "id", new[] { "Id cannot be null or empty and must start with 's'" } }
        });
    }

    return await next(invocationContext);
};

return Filter;
```

This is a purely functional approach:

- The filter factory is a function that takes an `EndpointFilterFactoryContext` and a filter (represented by EndpointDelegate) and returns a new filter.
- A filter is a function (represented by EndpointDelegate)

Comment: Thank you! That made things a lot more understandable for me. May I ask you though why doesn't the filter function that we're returning from our factory accept an EndpointFilterDelegate next parameter? I mean that from what I've seen filter methods usually take two parameters: the context and the next filter in the filter pipeline (or the endpoint handler itself).

Comment: Why is it the factory function that has the next filter in the pipeline (given as a parameter)? Isn't it more logical that the filter we're creating should know it?

Answer (score 0):

> (invocationContext)

is more or less an Anonymous method with `invocatonContext` as Parameter.

You can study on Lambda Expressions and how they work. In .Net its used heavily.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
//Here you see (number) same as (invocationContext)
var result = numbers.Where((number) => number > 3 && number < 8); // LINQ and lambda
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));
Console.ReadLine();
```